# What have i done wrong in this javascript calculation?

Tags: javascript, html

I have two inputs that can hold a value and where a value is typed in.
`calculate()` kinda do the job but I getting an error in the console :
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null(…)` 
But for `calculate()` I get only that error!

```
    if($sal>10){
         echo '<td>
         <input type="text" oninput="calculate()"  name="monthly_sum_019" id="monthly_sum_019" value="">
         <input type="hidden" class="input toggle all" id="monthly_sum_019" oninput="calculate()" value="" placeholder="'.$sal.'"></td>';       
    }else{
         echo '<td>
         <input type="text" oninput="calculate()"  name="monthly_sum_019" id=""  value="">
         <input type="hidden" class="input toggle all" id="monthly_sum_019" oninput="calculatez()"  value="'.$sal.'"></td>';
        }
```

And have 2 inputs that returns result of calculation:

```
if($sal>10){
     echo '<td>
     <input type="text" id="result" name="reward_019"  value=""></td>'; 
}else{
     echo '<td>
     <input type="text" id="result2"  name="reward_019"  value=""></td>';           
    }
```

And the javascript:

```
<script>
    function calculate() {
        var myBox1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('monthly_sum_019').value);  
        var myBox2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('norm').value);
        var myBox3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('time_hours_019').value);
        var result = document.getElementById('result'); 
        var myResult = (myBox1 / myBox2) * myBox3;

    result.value = myResult.toFixed(2);
    }   
</script>
<script>
    function calculatez() {
        var myBox1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('hourmoney').value);    
        var myBox3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('time_hours_019').value);
        var result2 = document.getElementById('result2');   
        var myResult = myBox3 * myBox1;
            result2.value = myResult.toFixed(2);                
    }
</script>
```

What is wrong?

Comment: `id=""` you meant to fill in some `id`?

Comment: @sabithpocker woops typo error

Comment: `id="hourmoney"` is missing from your dom. Try to set up a fiddle with your form and JS

Comment: @RazvanBalosin how it can be missing fi turns out that $sal>10 != true?

Comment: Because you have `id=""` instead of `id="hourmoney"` if `$sal > 10 != true`

Comment: Ok guys i got it working thanks!

Comment: here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xah0L9g6/) with your code. I've used 10 for the values where you set them with php

Comment: @RazvanBalosin you are demonstrating that half doesnt work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually `Cant do something of NULL` means you try to select element but it's not presented in DOM.

I see that you try to select element with ID `result2` but in your provided code I see that when `$sal > 10 == true` you do not put element with such ID.

Since it's PHP code you *can* have same ID in both `if` and `else` parts (but not in same part multiple times).

Comment: Hmm so what are the solution for this?

Comment: @IngusGraholskis Well, one obvious solution would be to make `id="result"` to `id="result2"`